# Convert list of datetimes to list of lists containing the count of datetimes for particular year and month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Supposing I have a list of datetimes as below:

```
datetimes = ['05.06.2018 11:11:11', '05.06.2018 11:11:05', '05.06.2018 11:11:00', '05.06.2018 11:10:17', '05.06.2018 11:10:10', '05.06.2018 11:10:04', '05.06.2018 11:09:58', '05.06.2018 11:09:52', '05.06.2018 11:09:39', '05.06.2018 11:09:27', '04.06.2018 11:48:01', '04.06.2018 11:47:58', '04.06.2018 11:47:55', '04.06.2018 11:47:52', '04.06.2018 11:47:49', '04.06.2018 11:47:47', '04.06.2018 11:47:44', '04.06.2018 11:47:41', '04.06.2018 11:47:30', '04.06.2018 11:47:22', '04.06.2018 11:47:18', '04.06.2018 11:47:15', '04.06.2018 11:47:10', '04.06.2018 11:47:07', '04.06.2018 11:47:04', '04.06.2018 11:47:02', '04.06.2018 11:46:59', '04.06.2018 11:46:55', '04.06.2018 11:46:53', '04.06.2018 11:46:50', '04.06.2018 11:46:47', '04.06.2018 11:46:44', '04.06.2018 11:46:41', '04.06.2018 11:46:38', '04.06.2018 11:46:35', '04.06.2018 11:46:32', '04.06.2018 11:46:27', '04.06.2018 11:46:24', '04.06.2018 11:46:21', '04.06.2018 11:46:19', '04.06.2018 11:46:16', '04.06.2018 11:46:13', '04.06.2018 11:46:10', '04.06.2018 11:46:07', '04.06.2018 11:46:04', '04.06.2018 11:46:01', '04.06.2018 11:45:58', '04.06.2018 11:45:27', '04.06.2018 11:45:24', '04.06.2018 11:45:21', '04.06.2018 11:45:18', '04.06.2018 11:45:16', '04.06.2018 11:45:13', '04.06.2018 11:45:10', '04.06.2018 11:44:17', '04.06.2018 11:44:14', '04.06.2018 11:44:10', '04.06.2018 11:44:07', '04.06.2018 11:44:04', '04.06.2018 11:44:01', '04.06.2018 11:43:57', '04.06.2018 11:43:53', '04.06.2018 11:43:15', '04.06.2018 11:41:48', '26.06.2017 12:04:24', '08.05.2017 11:32:03', '06.04.2017 10:20:04', '06.03.2017 11:21:59', '23.02.2017 11:34:23', '20.02.2017 09:49:23', '15.02.2017 11:17:23', '14.02.2017 10:00:53', '09.02.2017 14:13:09', '08.02.2017 12:51:51', '08.02.2017 12:50:49', '07.02.2017 13:31:40', '07.02.2017 13:30:45', '06.02.2017 12:20:44', '01.02.2017 11:51:06', '01.02.2017 11:31:33', '24.01.2017 11:12:23', '24.01.2017 10:59:01', '24.01.2017 10:57:42', '23.01.2017 11:15:06', '18.01.2017 12:57:40', '18.01.2017 10:26:22', '17.01.2017 12:02:10', '17.01.2017 12:00:51', '16.01.2017 11:23:39', '16.01.2017 11:21:32', '16.01.2017 11:15:47', '16.01.2017 11:12:24', '13.01.2017 11:15:18', '13.01.2017 11:14:06', '13.01.2017 11:13:29', '12.01.2017 13:33:57', '12.01.2017 13:33:29', '11.01.2017 13:32:47', '11.01.2017 13:19:55']
```

What would be the best way - through Pandas or pure Python - to create a list of as many lists as there are years, where each list would contain 12 integers representing count of datetimes for particular month under particular year?

For example if there are only two years in the `datetimes`, the `output` would be a list of two lists like this:

```
output = [[32, 12, 43, 54, 12, 34, 98, 56, 99, 100, 3213, 456], [76, 876, 233, 12, 121, 3342, 66, 44, 87, 1765, 321, 56]]
```

Comment: If some month is missing is necessary `0` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.groupby.html) by [`year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.year.html)
[`month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.month.html) with [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and convert to `list`s:

```
datetimes = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(datetimes))

L = (datetimes.groupby([datetimes.dt.year, datetimes.dt.month])
              .size()
              .groupby(level=0)
              .apply(list)
              .tolist())
print (L)
[[17, 4, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2], [54, 10]]
```

If want also add `0` for missing months add [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
datetimes = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(datetimes))

y = datetimes.dt.year
m = datetimes.dt.month
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([y.unique(), np.arange(1, 13)])

L = (datetimes.groupby([y, m])
              .size()
              .reindex(mux, fill_value=0)
              .groupby(level=0)
              .apply(list)
              .tolist()
              )
print (L)

[[17, 4, 0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 3, 1, 0, 2, 2], [0, 0, 0, 54, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```